# Clang ошибка компиляции

Tags: классы, clang

Пытаюсь освоить clang
Установить получилось по гайду
Из командной строки строит АСД

Но при попытке скомпилировать код из поста получаю ошибку

```
C:\Program Files\LLVM>clang++ -Iinclude F:\Checker\main.cpp -o F:\Checker\main.exe -std=c++14 
C:\Users\7A3D~1\AppData\ Local\Temp\main-fa984d.o: (.text+0x89): undefined reference to `clang_createIndex'
C:\Users\7A3D~1\AppData\ Local\Temp\main-fa984d.o: (.text+0xdd): undefined reference to `clang_parseTranslationUnit'
C:\Users\7A3D~1\AppData\ Local\Temp\main-fa984d.o: (.text+0x146): undefined reference to `clang_disposeTranslationUnit'
C:\Users\7A3D~1\AppData\ Local\Temp\main-fa984d.o: (.text+0x14f): undefined reference to `clang_disposeIndex'
clang++.exe: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Я так понимаю нужны библиотеки, чтобы clang_createIndex и др могли использоваться, но где они лежат и как их подключить я не знаю

Подскажите как решить?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <clang-c/Index.h>

int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
 CXIndex index = clang_createIndex (
         false, //     excludeDeclarationFromPCH
        true   // displayDiagnostics
 );
CXTranslationUnit unit = 
clang_parseTranslationUnit (
     index,                           
// CIdx
         "example.cpp",                      
// source_filename
         argv + 1 ,                        
// command_line_args
     argc - 1 ,                        
// num_command_line_args
         0,                                
// unsave_files
         0,                                
// num_unsaved_files
         CXTranslationUnit_None           
// options
 );
 if (unit != 0 )
         std::cout << "Translation unit successfully created" << std::endl;
 else
         std::cout << "Translation unit was not created" << std::endl;
 clang_disposeTranslationUnit(unit);
 clang_disposeIndex(index);
}
```

Comment: `-lclang` добавить, наверное?

Comment: Библиотека должна называться `[lib]clang.dll` ... подключаться должна с помощью `-L/path/to/lib -lclang`... возможно понадобятся и другие...  где лежит — ищи.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это не ошибка компиляции - она прошла удачно. Это ошибка линковки. У меня под линуксом скомпилировалось (и потом смог запустит) такой командой

```
g++ main.cpp -o main -I /usr/lib/llvm/5/include/ -L /usr/lib/llvm/5/lib64/ -lclang
```

У Вас же параметры будут аналогичны. `-I` (путь к заголовкам) уже указан (только у меня полный). `-L` - это путь к библиотекам. Скорее всего у Вас это будет `-L lib` или `-Llib64`. В любом случае, поищите, где лежат файлы с именем вида `libclang.dll` `clang.dll` `clang.lib` или подобными. `-lclang` - это указания линковщику (его запустит компилятор), подключить библиотеку с кодом.

Comment: Нашел то, что вы сказали `C:\Program Files\LLVM\bin\libclang.dll`, `C:\Program Files\LLVM\lib\libclang.lib`
Попытался снова и итого такой же:
`C:\Program Files\LLVM>clang F:\Checker\main.cpp -o F:\Checker\main.exe -Iinclude -Llib -llibclang
C:\Users\7A3D~1\AppData\Local\Temp\main-c465c7.o:(.text+0xc): undefined reference to std::ios_base::Init::Init()
…
clang.exe: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`
Не правильно подключаю?

Comment: Я бы использовал clang++ вместо clang

Comment: спасибо большое, все заработало!

Comment: я даже не знаю, что ответить. Переформулируйте вопрос и оформите как новый.